# Parsing XML for specific Value - PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

So I have a script I'm trying to write to only pull data from an XML file where the value is a specific word.

This is what my XML looks like:

```
  <Scan>
    <ScanDate>2020-06-25T08:58:31.7792998-04:00</ScanDate>
    <ValidatedOnline>true</ValidatedOnline>
  </Scan>
```

I'm specifically looking for where

```
<ValidatedOnline>false</ValidatedOnline>
```

This is what my PowerShell looks like:

```
$DevicePath = 'tcphost\file.xml'
[xml]$Scans = Get-Content $DevicePath
$DateTime = Get-Date
Select-Xml -Xml $Scans -XPath "//ValidatedOnline" | 
    Where-Object {$_.Node -match "false"} |
    Select -Property $DateTime.ToString(), $DevicePath -ExpandProperty node | 
    Out-File -FilePath 'destination\destination.txt' -NoClobber -Append
```

The problem I'm having is with the Where-Object. I can't for the life of me figure out how to correctly get what I am looking for, a value of false in the ValidatedOnline section of the XML. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to select the node directly with XPath :

```
Select-Xml -Xml $Scans -XPath "//ValidatedOnline[.="false"]" | 
     Select -Property $...
```

or as outlined by @js2010 :

```
Select-Xml -Xml $Scans -XPath "//ValidatedOnline" | 
    Where-Object {$_.Node.'#text' -match "false"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look under '#text':

```
Select-Xml -Xml $Scans -XPath "//ValidatedOnline" | % node

#text
-----
true
```